# Is there any way to parametrized schema name / table names in an SQL query?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-injection

I'm working on an issue with needing to parametrized an SQL query where the user selects a specific table? Sounds like this isn't possible from what I've read.

User input is not allowed on the Schema Name and Table Name as the end user is selecting from a list of provided options from the developer.

Here is a solution that would fail security code scanning:

```
if (connectionStringInfo.InitialCatalog == fileDetail.DestinationDetail.SelectedDatabaseName)
{
    using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(string.Format("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [{0}].[{1}]", ImportService.GetImporterSchemaName(), fileDetail.DestinationDetail.SelectedTableName)))
    {
        sqlCommand.Connection = conn;

        int recordCount = Convert.ToInt32(await sqlCommand.ExecuteScalarAsync());
        return recordCount;
    }
}
```

Here is the code to parametrize it, but it has an error:

```
if (connectionStringInfo.InitialCatalog == fileDetail.DestinationDetail.SelectedDatabaseName)
{
    using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [@SchemaName].[@DbTableName]"))
    {
        sqlCommand.Connection = conn;

        SqlParameter[] param = new SqlParameter[2];
        param[0] = new SqlParameter("@SchemaName", ImportService.GetImporterSchemaName());
        param[1] = new SqlParameter("@DbTableName", fileDetail.DestinationDetail.SelectedTableName);
        sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(param[0]);
        sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(param[1]);

        int recordCount = Convert.ToInt32(await sqlCommand.ExecuteScalarAsync());
        return recordCount;
    }
}
```

Error:

[image]

Is there any other way to fix this "security" wise besides adding a justification that it is not a user input?

Comment: If you read the allowed schema/table from a whitelist, and then use string interpolation for those values (rather than parameters), that generally resolves the security concern and passes security scanning, since you'd only be embedding trusted data in the string rather than direct user input.

Comment: `[{0}]` is not a proper, safe way of escaping identifiers; it will fail if the identifier contains a `]`. (Of course this "never happens" in a "proper" database, which is why this can go unnoticed for a long time.) This is why T-SQL provides `QUOTENAME`. Many and subtle are the pitfalls of string interpolation.